# REST API - Does the Token need to be returned in every response?

Tags: rest, token

I'm using Token based auth in my application. When the login credentials are first sent to the system, a token is returned. That token is then required with each and every request afterwards. When the token expires, a refresh token is used to determine if a new one should be issued. All pretty basic stuff.

What I've noticed is that the token isn't returned to the client with each web call. As in, client sends a message to the server with the token, server sends a response, but doesn't include the token unless it has been refreshed. Now, obviously thanks to client-side storage the token is still available.

My question is whether or not it is a best practice to return the token with each and every response, even if it is unchanged. Or if this really isn't a big deal and I can just stop worrying about it.

Comment: Old question but in case anyone sees this later... you're way better off following something like OAuth2 than building something else from scratch. All of these are solved problems, and by people who specialize in this.

Answer (score 1):

Generally no, the response should not contain the token as it's unnecessary at that point - the user has already been authenticated for that specific request and appropriate actions have been taken (either a 200 with data or 401 or whatever).

It is the responsibility of the client to know the token when making a request.